# Adobe AIR 3.6 - error 304: Initial window content is invalid (RuntimeError)

Tags: air, adobe, adt, packaging

**EDIT: Problem solved: App.swf was compressed using LZMA and that was wrong. SWF file must be pure.**

i'm working on cross-platform AIR application, and i've got an error: **"304: Initial window content is invalid (RuntimeError)"** when i'm running packaging on continous integration machine (windows), but on local computers (windows and mac) all works fine.
Here is my code of application XML descriptor file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">
    <id>com.test.App</id>
    <filename>App</filename>
    <name>App</name>
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>App.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    </initialWindow>
    <iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <!-- iPhone and iPod touch devices -->
                <string>1</string>
                <!-- iPad devices -->
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
            <!--<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>-->
            <!--<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>-->
            <!--<key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>-->
            <!--<string>YES</string>-->
            ]]>
        </InfoAdditions>
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone>
    <android>
        <manifestAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->
                <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>-->

                <!--<uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>-->
                <!--<application android:enabled="true">
                    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>-->
            </manifest>
            ]]>
            </manifestAdditions>
    </android>
</application>
```

The name of application SWF is the same as  value: "App.swf".
Here is how i run ADT tool to package application:

```
C:/tools/flexsdk/4.6.0_mobile_win/bin/adt -package -target apk-debug -storetype pkcs12 -keystore C:/certs/android_cert.pfx -storepass password C:/build/app/bin-debug/android/App.apk C:/build/app/script/App-app.xml C:/build/app/bin-debug/android/assets.xml C:/build/app/bin-debug/android/assets C:/build/app/bin-debug/android/App.swf
```

Any ideas will be very helpful guys :)

Comment: But how do you make sure the swf is not compressed? I've searched for solutions and found a solution saying I should use `-compress=false` but I don't know where I should put it. MXMLC doesn't like it, and neither does ADT

Comment: To avoid issues with LZMA compression and ADT mobile
application packaging you should add +configname=airmobile parameter to compiler when building swf